# Windows CMD: Sequential Commands for a Program

Tags: windows, cmd, command

Apologies if this is a very basic question, but I haven't been able to find any clarification elsewhere. I'm trying to run a program through Windows CMD (myprog), which requires input from the user when executed. What I would like to do is preload these input responses in a single command within CMD, which will then feed sequentially into the program's prompts.

I'm aware that multiple commands can be sequentially run using the '&' and '&&' operators, but the sequential commands will only be run once CMD returns to the default command prompt (if an input is requested, it is assumed the first command hasn't finished executing).

Current behaviour:

```
>: myprog && (input 1) && (input 2)
myprog: Please enter input 1! <manual input required>
myprog: Please enter input 2! <manual input required>
myprog: Program ends!
>: input 1
>: input 2
```

Desired behaviour:

```
>: myprog && (input 1) && (input 2)
myprog: Please enter input 1! <automatic input 1>
myprog: Please enter input 2! <automatic input 2>
myprog: Program ends!
```

Is it possible to pre-arrange multiple commands that will feed into a program, rather than waiting for the next instance of a blank command line? Please let me know if any additional clarification is required.

Cheers.

Comment: Input isn't passed on the command line. For a console application input is typically read either from the process standard input or directly from the console input buffer. If it's using standard input, then probably the answer from @HarryJohnston will suffice. Otherwise you'll need a program that starts `myprog` and then drives it by calling [`WriteConsoleInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687403), or using an automation tool such as [AutoHotkey](http://ahkscript.org) that can send input to the console window.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the target program, it may be as simple as

```
(echo input 1 & echo input 2) | myprog
```